# sql (or postgres) how to set the date as single year and month?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I am compiling data of multiple years but I only need time not date and year. How can I set the year and date data into a single year and a single date so that I can use the time information as accumulative data?
2020-01-01 + time value.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: You need to provide more details. In Postgres you can add a `time` value to `date` value, e.g. `date '2020-01-01'  + time '23:30:00'` which will yield a `timestamp` value.

Comment: What do you mean with "SQL or Postgres"? SQL is a query language used by all relational databases - including Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

The information you provided is a little light. Still with certain assumptions:

```
create table ts_sum (ts_fld timestamptz);

insert into ts_sum values ('2020-04-14 08:15:32'), ('2021-09-27 18:45:01'), ('2022-01-09 20:21:05');

select sum(to_char(ts_fld, 'HH24:MI:SS')::interval) from ts_sum;
   sum    
----------
 47:21:38
```

Needs to be tested with your data. The procedure is extract the time portion out of the timestamp using [to_char](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) then cast that to an [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) and then `sum` the time intervals.